# Subquery table-alias not being recognized in JOIN-ON/WHERE

Tags: mysql, outer-join, table-alias

I'm trying to lend some help to a hobbyist friend, using SQL Server experience to help with MySQL.

He's working on a game database. I wrote this query for him

```
SELECT ib.itemid, ii.realname as name, ib.stackSize,
       IFNULL(ah.price, '-') as price, ah.stock
    FROM item_basic ib
    LEFT OUTER JOIN item_info as ii ON ii.itemID = ib.itemID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT price, COUNT(*) as stock
        FROM auction_house
        GROUP BY itemID) as AH on ii.itemID = AH.itemID -- erring line
    ORDER BY ii.realname
```

And a version that used assembled the subquery in the FROM cluse rather than a JOIN, but that was less troublesome than this version.

#### This gives the error **`Unknown column 'ah.itemID' in 'on clause'`**

If I change the erring line, incorrectly, to `... ii.itemID = ib.itemID`, the query executes, but of course the results are incorrect (exponentially doubled in this case).

Here's an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9255d4/7)** with sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not selecting itemID in your subquery. In addition, you're selecting the price column without aggregating by it. Try replacing

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT price, COUNT(*) as stock
        FROM auction_house
        GROUP BY itemID) as AH on ii.itemID = AH.itemID
```

with

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT itemID, price, COUNT(*) as stock
        FROM auction_house
        GROUP BY itemID, price) as AH on ii.itemID = AH.itemID
```

Comment: It's so obvious. I became so focused, and missed the obvious thing. Thanks for the fresh eyes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `AH.itemID`, you can only access the results of a subquery.

Comment: ...DUH, couldn't see the forest for the trees.